# Short (<3m) CANBUS line termination for two devices

Tags: can

I have two devices communicating through CANBUS (250-500kbps) via short (few metres) wire. Should I put 120 Ohm resistor to each end of it, or just 60 Ohm in the middle? Maybe it is not necessary at all?

Comment: where on earth did you get the idea that 60 ohms in the middle would be a good plan? Perhaps you'd draw a diagram of exactly what nodes these end 120 ohm resistors are connected between.

Comment: well two 120 ohm in parallel is 60 ohm

Comment: We've tried many termination configurations for CAN (one end of the bus open circuited, 100 Ohm termination, 150 Ohm termination, 100 Ohm impedance cable, etc.). If the bus is short and the speed is slow, just about anything seems to work. As you can guess, termination and cable impedance matters for longer busses or faster speeds. That being said, you'll never regret using the proper termination and cable impedance.

Answer (score 1):

For any serious product, place 120R in each end of the physical bus, period.

For lab/experiment purposes such as playing with evaluation boards, testing firmware or other such experiments sitting on your desktop, then yeah you'll get away with placing around 60R at some random location.

(I frequently manage to connect "too many" terminators - as in having a bus with 120R + 120R then add a third one on a PCB connected to a stub - this never causes any problems while just sitting on my desktop with minimal bus lengths.)

Failing to provide roughly 60R between CANH and CANL will however cause spurious communication problems at such relatively high baud rates, especially if you skip terminating resistors entirely.